# Why does the Alternating Series Test require $b_n$ to be > 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So one of the prerequisites for applying the alternating series test is that the serie is of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}b_n$$
Where $b_n$ has to be greater than 0. I was wondering why $b_n$ has to be greater than zero?

It would obviously still alternate if $b_n$ was less than zero, so why is this a condition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having $b_n<0$ for all $n$ is as good as looking as the series $\sum (-1)^n|b_n|$ rather than $\sum (-1)^{n-1}b_n$. This is still an alternating series. I think you probably mean what would happen if $b_n<0$ for some $n$?

Comment: Take $b_n=(-1)^{n}$ in Alteranting Series Test to see why it is necessary to assume that $b_n >0$.

Comment: @R_D Indeed, what I mean to ask is why $b_n$ has to be more than zero for any $n$.

Comment: The Alternating Series Test simply applies to series where **successive terms are of opposite sign**. One way to say this mathematically is to say that the n-th term is $(-1)^{n-1}b_n$ where $b_n > 0$ for every $n$. But there are other ways to write it too.

Comment: If $b_n$ is not strictly $>0$ for all $n$, then it might so happen that the sum becomes a sum of just positive or negative numbers(for example), instead of alternating. An example might if $b_n$ alternates signs with the $(-1)^{n-1}$, so $(-1)^{n-1}b_n$ will always stay at the same sign.

Comment: A slightly more general form of the alternating series test would be this: If $b_n$ converges to $0$ monotonously, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n b_n$ converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no principal difference between series where all $b_n > 0$ and where all $b_n< 0$ from convergence point of view. Convergence of 2 such series are equivalent and sum differs, when exists, by $−1$.

Analogically, there is no difference in alternating series from convergence point of view if we consider all $b_n > 0$ and/or where all $b_n< 0$. If $b_n < 0$, then we can write $b_n = - (-b_n)$ and take minus out of summing in partial sums and, if series converged, out of infinite sum and consider convergence question for $(-b_n) > 0$: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}b_n=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}(-b_n)$.